# I can't delete or access a download

Tags: pantheon-files

When I go to my downloads, there is a minus symbol on the bottom left on the icon of my downloads. I can't move to trash or move it at all. This started after I changed the properties on one of my downloads. Please help.

Comment: All file and folder are locked... Cant delete. Tried ( sudo rem file name) but not working plz help